# Questions regarding selling "mitzvah" items to Christians for use in their Church service

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, matzah, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

My understanding is that one is not aloud to intentionally sell anything to an *oved avodah zarah* ("idol worshipper") if he knows that he will use that item for his idol worshipping purpose.

There are two "mitzvah items" that I have seen Christians use as part of their Church service, and regarding each of these, I'm curious if this prohibition applies:

1. Can one sell pieces of his *lulav* to a Christian for him to use as part of Palm Sunday services?
2. Can one sell matzot shel mitzvah (i.e. - those specially baked for Pesach Seder use) to a Christian who uses them as the "host" as part of mass?

Factors to include in your answer, if applicable include:

- any halachot of Jews selling items to Gentiles for their worship purposes
- any special *kedusha* (holiness) status to left-over lulavim or matzot after the holidays
- whether today's Christians are in the category of *aku"m* (idol worshippers) even if they do attend a service, occasionally.

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50750. Perhaps [edit] this so it's less of a duplicate?